# Ethics of Advaita Vedanta

Tags: advaita, ethics, evil

How is the problem of metaphysical, natural and moral evil resolved within traditional Advaita Vedanta?

Comment: It is just a philosophical theory and it does not hv any practical utility ..

Comment: My question is related to philosophy, theory. I didn't ask about practical aspects. Indeed, instead of 'resolved' I could use the word 'explained'.

Comment: okay fine .. and u can always edit the question